# Convert manual transforms to standard xdt

Tags: .net, web-deployment, msdeploy, xdt-transform

So I want to convert out .Net app from using some prior method of manual transforms into a xdt style as referenced by Troy Hunt http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html. I am not too familiar with transforms currently, and I think I might just need a prod in the right direction.

How can I transform the following so that I can change the file path c:\logs\blah.log in the web config?

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Asplogger" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\logs\blah.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="NHibernate.SQL" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <!--Namespace-->
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <!--level of errors to report INFO, ERROR, FATAL-->
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="NHibernate.SQL" />
    </logger>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="Asplogger" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Would it be something like this?

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingAppender">
      <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"
        key="file value" value="path.that.I.want"/>
    </appender>      
   </log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to match on name instead of key

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <file xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
            value="path.that.I.want.log"/>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```